How to check in Swift packages
On the whole, I prefer Swift Package Manager to Cocoapods.  However, there is a shortcoming: With Cocoapods, I can "check-in" the dependencies into my project.  This saves team members the trouble of having to run pod install every time they pull changes.
However, I can't find a way to do this with Swift Packages.  It seems the best I can do is commit changes to the package files. This still leaves team members with the issue of having to go file ->  update swift packages.  And if they forget, they might have frustrating errors if they don't realize a package update is needed.

If you have your package.swift file(s) and the resolution files checked in, there shouldn’t be anything other users need to do — Xcode will download the dependencies automatically.

It should, but it doesn't always, hence the need to "check in".

It's also super slow to update dependencies.

Sometimes not updating when manually specifying the exact dependency (not just "up until major")

Just wanted to pile in on this, I just cracked open a project which imports swift packages, and as I was concerned about, didn't start updating the packages.  So the compiler flagged errors all over my project because it was referencing types inside the packages. This was too overwhelming for xcode and so I had to force quit it.  If I was able to check in my packages...
